# C# JSON deserialization of current Thread

Tags: c#, json, reflection, deserialization

i want to do JSON serialization on the current thread, and deserialize it by reflection.

i succeeded to do the serialization:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(empty));
string ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);
```

But I didn't succeed  to do the deserializtaion..

How can I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: what errors did you get? what does the object you are deserialising look like?

Comment: Wait, are you tying to serialize a `Thread`, I don't think thats possible

Comment: I wrote:  Thread w = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thread>(ser); and the exception:   "Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.Threading.Thread. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute"  was thrown..

Comment: I also tried to make casting to Thread, and it didn't work.

Comment: When i printed the string 'ser' to the screen, It was looking O.K...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error you posted in your comment: *"A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute."*

System.Threading.Thread meets none of these requirements: it has no default constructor, multiple constructors taking arguments, and none are marked with the JsonConstructor attribute.

What are you looking to achieve by serializing a thread object?

Comment: I want to send (via UDP) the threads that running on first project, to another project.
The second project will examine the prop. values ​​of the receiving threads.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I mean, you'd have to pickle a massive amount of the operating system state and restore it to copy a thread from one machine to another. Rule of thumb: serialization should be used to transfer *data*, not *state*.